# Sufficient conditions for the compact immersion of $H_0^1(\Omega)$ into $L^2(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations, compact-operators

Is it true that if $\Omega$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^d$ (not necessarily a bounded one) on which the following functional admits a minimum point
$$ \int_{\Omega} \lvert \nabla u \rvert ^2  \quad \text{with} \quad u \in H_0^1(\Omega),\, \int_{\Omega} u^2 dx=1;$$
then the inclusion of $H_0^1(\Omega)$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ is compact? If it is not true could someone please give me a counterexample?

Comment: In a counterexample, $\Omega$ must be unbounded, since $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is compactly embedded in $L^2(\Omega)$ for all open and bounded $\Omega$.

Comment: @gerw sorry, that comment was a bit redudant, I should have said unbounded from the start.